# Laravel Homestead dynamic mapping

Tags: php, regex, homestead

I just found out that Laravel Homestead allows dynamic domains mapping. In [this tutorial](http://dan.hersam.com/2015/02/24/wildcard-site-for-laravel-homestead/) author described his mappings this way:

```
sites:
    - map: '~^(?<project>.+)\.app$'
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/\$project/public
```

I want to have all .dev domains mapped automatically, plus I'm using actual domain folder name, so I changed it in the snippet and I simplified it a little. What I got it this:

```
sites:
    - map: ~(?<project>.+)
      to: /home/vagrant/www/\$project/public
```

It works perfectly, but I'm curious if it can be simplified even more. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
sites:
    - map: ~.+
      to: /home/vagrant/www/\$0/public
```

Neither does this:

```
sites:
    - map: ~(.+)
      to: /home/vagrant/www/\$1/public
```

I'd like to understand this syntax better.

Comment: Numeric captures are said to work unless they are overwritten at some point. Please check further lines.

Comment: There's nothing further to this section.

Comment: I refer to [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) saying *A named regular expression capture can be used later as a variable*, and *the captures can also be used in digital form*, but *such usage should be limited to simple cases (like the above), since the digital references can easily be overwritten*. I am not sure what can overwrite them, so the safest way is to use the **named captures** here.

Comment: Does my comment answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, please add it as an answer if you'd like to get a few points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *named captures* here is the safest way here. As per [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names):

> A **named regular expression capture can be used later as a variable**
> ...
>   The captures **can also be used in digital form**:

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(.+)$;

    location / {
        root   /sites/$2;
    }
}
```

> However, **such usage should be limited to simple cases** (like the above), since **the digital references can easily be overwritten**.

Comment: Thanks! Those digital references don't work for me at all though. There's a new problem I've encountered, could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091959/dnsmasq-stopped-working-for-no-reason

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I hope you will get a proper answer for that question soon, too.