# Dnsmasq stopped working for no reason

Tags: osx-yosemite, homestead, dnsmasq

I started using Dnsmasq on OSX Yosemite to resolve all *.dev domains to 192.168.10.10 IP address, which is Laravel Homestead's default.

It worked for me, but after sleeping and waking my Macbook, it stopped working.

I have followed steps of [this tutorial](http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/), at first and it worked. It seems like all needed files are still there, but now when I go to `anything.dev`, it loads forever and then timeouts.

I do have a `dev` file at `/etc/resolver` with following content:

```
nameserver 192.168.10.10
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on this?

Comment: @JimGreenleaf it works for me now, I forgot about this issue. I can help you with it tomorrow, ok? :)